# I have to define a python function that returns a list of all the inbuilt python methods and functions present in a dataset of python questions

Tags: python, regex

I am working with a dataset of python questions for students. The dataset contains questions like the one below.

> **What will be the output of the following Python code?**
>
> ```
> x = 50
> def func():
>     global x
>     print('x is', x)
>     x = 2
>     print('Changed global x to', x)
> func()
> print('Value of x is', x)
> ```

**Note**:I have formatted the question this way here but in the dataset, this whole question is a large string, and the code and the text part aren't separate
I have to generate a list with all the inbuilt python functions and methods that are present in a question given in the dataset. A list with only one element like this **["print()"]** should be returned for this question given above. I have to combine all the unique functions that are used in the dataset of all the questions, into a single list.
I have to then use this list of functions to count the frequencies of all the functions in the list that occur in one question of the dataset. I will loop through the entire dataset to get this information for each question in the dataset.

Here are the problems that I am facing.

1. If I use regex to find functions in the text, I will also get the function **func()** that is user-defined in the question, but in every question in the dataset, a custom function is defined first using the **def** keyword. How can I use this to my advantage and filter out user-defined functions from the inbuilt functions?
2. I am new to regex and hence I cannot think of how to write a robust regex function that will return all inbuilt functions and methods from the text. (**Note**: While functions are called in a new line or with a space in front, methods are called like this: **list.append('a')**. Here I need the regex to identify only **append()** as a method and not **list.append()**.

Comment: Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this. You need a proper Python parser.

Comment: If you can get all of the functions out, then you can simply filter the whole list by checking for membership in `__builtins__`, which is normally a module.

Comment: @LMD The problem is that the code part and the question part aren't separate. It is one whole string and that is why I cannot use a parser, Also some questions like **What does the len() function do?** don't even have a code part but still has a function.

Comment: "I have to then use this list of functions to count the frequencies of all the functions in the list that occur in one question of the dataset." Why not just start with a list of *all* Python builtins, count their uses, and then ignore anything that had a count of 0?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, I need the list of all unique functions in the whole dataset and then use the count of each function as a feature for an ML model.

Answer (score -1):

1. As was suggested in the comments you can use `__builtins__`. `dir(__builtins__)` will give you a list of names of all builtin objects. You'll need the lower portion of that list, which is where the functions are.
2. As for the regex... You can build a list of builtins as suggested in (1) and then use it in a regex like this:

```
import re

rex = re.compile(f"({'|'.join(builtins)})\s*\(")
```

That uses the fact that a function name must be followed by an opening parenthesis. The closing parenthesis you can add later, when building the resulting list.

Comment: Thank you, this certainly solves half of my problem but I also need to identify different methods. How can I do that?

Comment: Now, that *would* require a parser. There's no way to tell an object's type syntactically, so there's no way to tell from just the code if an object (and therefore its methods) is builtin or not. Though as an approximation you could make a list of methods and use `"\.{'|'.join(methods)}\s*\(` or combine both regex into one. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) is very helpful btw, if you haven't heard about it before.